# How to get the var_dump($_POST) to meet this structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jsfiddle

I have a jsfiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ybZvv/61/

Please follow steps in fiddle:

1. When you open fiddle, click on "Add Question" button twice, this will append 2 rows.
2. In first row select answer buttons "A" and "C", in second row select answer buttons "A", "B" and "E". The checkbox values for each answer button selected is displayed underneath.

The problem is though is the structure when I do a var_dump($_POST).

The current structure of the var_dump($_POST) looks like this:

```
array(3) { 
  ["numQuestion"]=> array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(1) "1" 
    [1]=> string(1) "2" 
  }  
  ["submitDetails"]=> string(14) "Submit Details"
  ["value"]=> array(4) { 
    ["answerARow"]=> string(2) "on" 
    ["answerCRow"]=> string(2) "on" 
    ["answerBRow"]=> string(2) "on" ["answerERow"]=> string(2) "on"
  } 
}
```

I want it to look like below:

```
array(3) {
  ["numQuestion"]=> array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(1) "1" 
    [1]=> string(1) "2"
  }
  ["submitDetails"]=> string(14) "Submit Details"
  ["value"]=> array(5) {
    [1]=> array(2) {
      [0]=> string(1) "A"
      [1]=> string(1) "C"
    }
    [2]=> array(3) {
      [0]=> string(1) "A" 
      [1]=> string(1) "B" 
      [2]=> string(1) "E"
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how the code can be manipulated in order to reach this structure?

Virtually what the structure should look like is that there are 2 questions, for question 1 the answers are A and C, for question 2 the answers are A,B and E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of generating `value[answerCRow]` in your checkboxes, try to create them as:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="hiddenanswerHRow0value" name="value[" + iQuestionIndex + "][]"  value="A" checked="">
```

where, your value will be iterating.

The jQuery's `updateAnswer` function will have this line:

```
var input = '<input type="checkbox" id="' + hid + '" name="value[' + iQuestionIndex + '][]" value="' + value + '" checked /><label for="' + hid + '">' + value + '</label>';
_oCurrAnswerContainer.append(input);
```

Comment: So are you saying change `.attr('id', $this.attr('id') + 'Row')` to `.attr('id', $this.attr('id') + 'Row' + qnum + 'value')`?

Comment: @user1701484 Check the edit. Also, update #65 on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybZvv/65/)

Comment: Oh sorry you said checkbox not button sorry bout that lol. Ok so after I insert this line then shall I text the var_dump($_POST) again and see what output is?

Comment: Just tested te var_dump($_POST) and the structure looks great. Thank you for your help :)